# Laravel 5.3 : Error while fetch data in view using foreach

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

i got error while i'm trying to fetch my data in view. This is my code : 
**controller**

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $tag = Tag::groupBy('name')->pluck('name');
    $tags = json_encode($tag);

    return view('backend.articles.create', compact('categories', 'tags'));
}
```

**view**

*fetch data categories*

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <div class="checkbox">
           <label>
                  {!! Form::checkbox('category_id[]', $category->id) !!} {{ $category->name }}
           </label>
        </div>
    @endforeach
 </div>
```

*fetch data tags*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#tags').magicSuggest({
            cls: 'form-control',
            data: {!!$tags!!},
            @if (count(old('tags')))
            value: [
                @foreach (old('tags') as $tag)
                        '{{$tag}}',
                @endforeach
            ]
            @endif
        });
    });
```

I dont know why i got this error message : **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**. Could anybody to help me to fix this problem ?

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia Yes, i get all `categories` and `tags` data

Answer (score 0):

view

```
<div class="panel-body">
@if($categories)
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label>
              {!! Form::checkbox('category_id[]', $category->id) !!} {{ $category->name }}
       </label>
    </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#tags').magicSuggest({
        cls: 'form-control',
        data: {!!$tags!!},
        @if (is_array(old('tags')))
        value: [
            @foreach (old('tags') as $tag)
                    '{{$tag}}',
            @endforeach
        ]
        @endif
    });
});
```

Try to use is_array to make sure old('tags') returning array, I believe the problem because the old('tags') is not returning array.

Comment: unfortunately brother, i still get the error message `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: @Adi, what does `is_array(old('tags'))` give?

Comment: Ah, then it must be the from the $categories

try to check the if(is_array($categories)) before the loop

Comment: Correction, don't use is_array, just check if the $categories is not null
@if($categories) {
// the $categories loop
}

Comment: @BagusTesa : excuse me, what do you mean ?

Comment: nah, tried `{{ dd(is_array(old('tags'))) }}`? i wonder whether its an array or not.

Comment: @BagusTesa i got false

Comment: oh great, that's why you get error (its not an array, so it's invalid for `for..each`).. now, try `{{ dd(is_array(old('tags'))) }}`, what does it gave you? @Adi

Comment: @BagusTesa whats the different between `{{ dd(is_array(old('tags'))) }}` and `dd(is_array(old('tags'))) }}` ?. how if you make an answer for this question ?

Comment: check if the value of `$categories` `dd($categories);`

Comment: @Adi, sorry, my bad.. i mean `{{ dd(old('tags')) }}` it'll print the content of `old('tags')` just like php's `var_dump(..)` but with a little better formatting.

Comment: @BagusTesa i got `null`

Comment: oh well, sorry, it's my fault for not reading all of your code.. basically, for `$tags = json_encode($tag);` doesn't need to use [`old(..)`, its for old input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-old). while your data is **json encoded** it will be a string in json format, it is valid for your `data: {!!$tags!!},`. Hovewer, it is not valid for your `foreach` loop, i can only suggest: replace `$tags = json_encode($tag);` with `$tags = $tag`,

Comment: replace `data: {!!$tags!!},` with `data: {!! json_encode($tags) !!},`, `is_array(old('tags'))` with `is_array($tags)`, finally `@foreach (old('tags') as $tag)` with `@foreach($tags as $tag)`. @Adi

Comment: @BagusTesa unfortunately, the code isn't work, still get the same error message

Comment: can you `{{ dd($tags) }}` again?

Comment: @BagusTesa `Collection {#270 ▼ #items: [] }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131855/discussion-between-bagus-tesa-and-adi).